# current/previous node relations in spring data neo4j (LinkedList)

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, linked-list, spring-data-neo4j

I’m trying to create linked list of nodes with `CURRENT/PREVIOUS` relation similar to the picture below.

[image: this picture]

I'm not sure if my solution is the right way to handle this scenario, but to achieve that I created two nodes with a single method to populate new messages as below:

```
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "LATEST")
    private Message message;
    
    void newMessage(Message newMessage) {
        newMessage.setPrevious(message);
        message = newMessage;
    }
}
    
@Builder
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String text;

    @Relationship(type = "PREVIOUS")
    private Message previous;
}
```

I also created a sample code to test this solution:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class NewsFeedApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(NewsFeedApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(PersonRepository personRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Person personToAdd1 = Person.builder().name("John").build();
            personToAdd1.newMessage(Message.builder().text("first message").build());
            personToAdd1.newMessage(Message.builder().text("second message").build());
            personToAdd1.newMessage(Message.builder().text("third message").build());

            personRepository.save(personToAdd1);

            personToAdd1.newMessage(Message.builder().text("New message.").build());

            personRepository.save(personToAdd1);
        };
    }
}
```

I feel like I'm close, but I don't know how to reset the previous `CURRENT` relation and my solution produces output as:

[image: invalid solution]

So the question is:

- If my approach is okay, how could I remove previous `CURRENT` relation.
- If this approach is wrong, how could I implement linked list with CURRENT/PREVIOUS relations for nodes correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the missing puzzle, i.e. detaching the supplier relation. I don't know why I assumed in advance that this relation should be deleted automatically by the spring data repository "save" method.

Working solution:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Supplier, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (n:Person {name: $name})-[r:LATEST]->() DELETE r")
    void detachLatestFromPerson(String name);
}
```

```
    void newMessage(PersonRepository personRepository, Message newMessage) {
        personRepository.detachLatestFromPerson(name);
        newMessage.setPrevious(message);
        message = newMessage;
    }
```

PS. I still have doubts, as I'm not sure if that's a good approach to handle this scenario, so if you know a better solution, go ahead and post it, we can always swap the 'best answer' :)